# Using || to perform null / undefined check in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've read code that has snippets similar to this but I obviously forgot the semantics:

```
        let serve = target || "Hello World";
```

In other words if target is `null`, the serve equals `Hello World`.  My goal, since target is null, is to get serve to be `Hello Word` ...

If I run the function as stated node prints this:

```
ReferenceError: target is not defined
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Whats the question?

Comment: Updated the question ... I

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot reference a variable that was never declared.

Comment: remove the target if it is not there :)

Comment: Geez - Ok thanks!  I thought it would also work for undefined / undeclared variables ...

Comment: FWIW, you can check a variable that may or may not have been declared by doing `typeof target === "undefined"`, and it won't throw a reference error if it doesn't exist, although ideally you'd just make sure to declare it in the first place.

Comment: @Ole: If you want to be sure that you don't use variables you haven't declared, I'd recommend using [eslint](https://eslint.org/). You can set it up to show you errors for things like undeclared variables.
Best to keep the code clean and avoid unnecessary checks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the variable `target` first. Here are some examples:

```js
let target;
let serve = target || "Hello World";
console.log(serve); // prints "Hello World";

target = null;
serve = target || "Hello World";
console.log(serve); // still prints "Hello World";

target = "Cat";
serve = target || "Hello World";
console.log(serve); // prints "Cat"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `a || b` will return `b` if `a` is falsy. The falsy values from [You Don't Know JS: Types and Grammar - Chapter 4: Coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#falsy-values) are:

- `undefined`
- `null`
- `false`
- `+0`, `-0`, and `NaN`
- `""`

If you'd like to return the default **only** when `target` is `null`, use:

```
let serve = target === null ? "Hello World" : target;
```

Answer (score 2):

`target`, in your example is not `null`. It isn't anything: You haven't declared it at all.

```js
let target = null;
let serve = target || "Hello World";
console.log(serve);
```

Possibly you are thinking of the pattern:

```js
var serve = serve || "Hello World";
console.log(serve);
```

Which:

- Uses `var` to ensure that `serve` is a declared variable
- Assigns `"Hello World"` to serve is some previous code hasn't already assigned it a true value.